# Finding the pdf of a function

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X have pdf $f_X(x)=\frac{2}{9}(x+1)$, $-1$ less than or equal to $x$ less than or equal to $2$.

I have to find the pdf of $Y=X^2$.

I notice that I am not able to use that familiar theorem of differentiation and inverses. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could find the cdf $F_Y(y)$ of $Y$, and then differentiate. Clunky, but one retains control of the logic.

The only interesting part is for $0\lt y\lt 4$.

For $0\lt y\lt 1$, we have 
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(X^2\le y)=\Pr(-\sqrt{y}\le X\le \sqrt{y})=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{2}{9}(x+1)\,dx.$$

For $1\le y\lt 4$, things are a little simpler, and 
$$F_Y(y)=\int_{-1}^\sqrt{y}\frac{2}{9}(x+1)\,dx.$$

Since we want the pdf, we do not need to integrate then differentiate, we can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.